# The mysql configuration file my.cnf does not contain the variable open_file_limit

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I am trying to change the value of the variable open_file_limit. But the configuration file is empty:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you don't explicitly specify it, you'll get the default value ([5000 in 5.7](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_open_files_limit)). If you want to change this, you could just add it, e.g.:

```
open_files_limit = 8192
```

Comment: When adding the value. Example open_file_limit = 5000 I save the configuration file but when restarting the service the following error appears        Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

Comment: @JuanMaldonado If you share those logs it would be easier to help you

Comment: Write the question better here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48216459/errors-when-running-mysqldump-23-out-of-resources-when-opening-file-and-24-too-m thanks